# Need a "rolling" list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, result-accumulation

I have 32 columns of annual data in varying lengths which I can simulate as follows:

```
 SeedRandom[23458];
lengths = RandomInteger[{50, 100}, 32];
cols = RandomReal[{0, 1}, #] & /@ lengths;
```

From this I need successive accumulations of ten years. So I have two questions. First, how do I Join multiple years? There is surely something more elegant than this

```
    Join[cols[[1]], cols[[2]], cols[[3]], 
  cols[[4]](*...and so forth through cols[[10]]*)];
```

Second, how do I get a sequence which accumulates the first ten years, then years 2-11, then years 3-12, then years 4-13 and so forth through to years 23-32?

Comment: Instead of `Join[cols[[1]], cols[[2]], cols[[3]],...` you can just do `Flatten[cols]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[23458];
lengths = RandomInteger[{50, 100}, 32];
cols = RandomReal[{0, 1}, #] & /@ lengths;
```

This gives you the parts from 1-10, 2-11 ..

```
parts10 = Partition[cols, 10, 1]
```

The joined data is:

```
ts = Join @@@ parts10;
```

---

Within each of the joined lists:

```
acc1 = Table[Accumulate[ts[[i]] ], {i, 1, Length@ts}]
ListLinePlot[acc1]
```

[image]

Another variation could be:

```
acc2 = FoldList[Plus, #] & /@ ts;
acc1 == acc2
```

(* True *)

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html):

```
blockaccumulated = BlockMap[Accumulate@*Apply[Join], cols, 10, 1];

ListLinePlot[blockaccumulated]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
SeedRandom[23458];
lengths = RandomInteger[{50, 100}, 32];
cols = RandomReal[{0, 1}, #] & /@ lengths;

test1[ii1_, ii2_] := Join[Flatten@Table[cols[[i]], {i, ii1, ii2}]];
```

Testing this against the manual construction

```
test2 = Join[cols[[1]], cols[[2]], cols[[3]], cols[[4]], cols[[5]], 
   cols[[6]], cols[[7]], cols[[8]], cols[[9]], cols[[10]]];

LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[test1[1, 10] - test2]
```

> [image: true]

Not sure I understand what you meant when you said [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html), but if I am right, you can accumulate from year `xx1` to `xx2` like so:

```
accum[xx1_, xx2_] := 
 Accumulate[Flatten@Table[cols[[i]], {i, xx1, xx2}]]
```

From year 2 to 11

```
accum[2, 11]
```

> [image: accumulate]

Answer (score 4):

Overnight I came up with this, but some of the other suggestions are more efficient

```
rolling[data_List, n_] := Module[{series},
  series = Flatten[data[[n ;; n + 9]]];
  Length[series]
  ]
Table[rolling[data, i], {i, 1, 23}]
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 4):

Over the years I've seen similar problems where you would think `MovingMap[ ]` would be the key to the solution, but it is super-awkward to use, so I made this simplified version that I use frequently.

```
simpleMovingMap[f_, data_, numInWindow_] := f /@ Partition[data, numInWindow, 1];
```

Applying to your problem, using much smaller data

```
SeedRandom[23458];
lengths = RandomInteger[{2, 3}, 10];
cols = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, #] & /@ lengths;
```

gives

```
{{3, 4}, 
{5, 5}, 
{5, 2, 7},
 {9, 2}, 
{4, 4}, 
{1, 3, 10}, 
{6, 5, 10},
 {8, 6, 0}, 
{4, 8, 5}, 
{0, 1, 9}}
```

Computing what you want, combining runs of 3 years instead of 10.

```
res = simpleMovingMap[Flatten, cols, 3];
```

\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 3 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 2 & 7 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 5 & 5 & 5 & 2 & 7 & 9 & 2 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 5 & 2 & 7 & 9 & 2 & 4 & 4 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 9 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 10 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 4 & 4 & 1 & 3 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 10 & \text{} \\
 1 & 3 & 10 & 6 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 0 \\
 6 & 5 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 0 & 4 & 8 & 5 \\
\end{array}